# Sequlize nodejs table

Tags: mysql, node.js, postgresql, sequelize-typescript

I'm currently working on a project which has three tables,

1. Consumers
   2)Consumer_orders
   3)Consumer_order_items

The Consumers primary key id is fk to Consumer_orders with column name consumer_id.
The Consumer_orders pk id is fk to Consumer_order_items with column name consumer_order_id.

So I need to create a Get API with showing who paid for the order( paid is a boolean column added in Consumers),by that in get API it will show all users in db who have paid for the order
showing:
the consumer name,consumer orders,consumer order items

I'm stuck.I dont know how to fetch the data from the 3rd table to which no relation created from 1st table

Answer (score 0):

[From the sequelize docs](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/eager-loading.html#including-everything)

So maybe you can do something like

```
Consumers.findAll({
  where: { paid: true },
  include: { all: true, nested: true }
});
```